# Changing the 'Run As:' field for a scheduled task via C#

Tags: c#

I need to write a C# program to change the 'Run As' field of scheduled tasks on remote systems.

What are some of the libraries I should be looking at to achieve this?

Comment: Yup. Haven't had a chance to try the solutions out yet, but once I do, I will definitely accept an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can spawn a process to call [SCHTASKS.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Here is some code that I used to do just that:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "SCHTASKS.exe";
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(
    "/Change /S {0} /TN {1} /RU {2}\\{3} /RP {4}",
    MachineName,
    ScheduledTaskName,
    activeDirectoryDomainName,
    userName,
    password
);

p.Start();
// Read the error stream first and then wait.
string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(error))
{
    throw new Exception(error);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by activeDirectoryDomainName?

Comment: I am first trying to achieve the same on my local machine, so I ommitted MachineName from the list of arguments, so it defualts to local system

Comment: activeDirectoryDomainName is just the windows domain for the login.  If you are part of the domain, then your login looks something like this: `domain\username`.  Otherwise, it looks like this: `username`

Answer (score 1):

maybe :
http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/02/23/calling-the-task-scheduler-in-windows-vista-and-windows-server-2008-from-managed-code.aspx
?