# Check for Scheduled Task Existence and Check state

Tags: c#

I am using the following code to change the 'Run As:' username and password for a scheduled task on a remote host.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "SCHTASKS.exe";
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

//p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/Change /TN {0} /RU {1} /RP {2}",ScheduledTaskName,userName,password);
p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(
    "/Change /S {0} /TN {1} /TR {2} /RU {3}\\{4} /RP {5}", 
    MachineName, ScheduledTaskName, taskPath, activeDirectoryDomainName, userName, password);

p.Start();
// Read the error stream first and then wait.
string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. How can I check if the specified service exists at all, so that if it does not exist, I can just quit the program.
2. How can i check to see if the scheduled task is running or disabled?
3. If the scheduled task is disabled, can I still change the credentials, or is it like a Windows service where credentials cannot be changed if it is disabled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the link I gave you in [my last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017348/changing-the-run-as-field-for-a-scheduled-task-via-c/4017372#4017372).  The link for [SCHTASKS.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357(VS.85).aspx).

Look at the section called `Querying for Task Information.`

Here is my code to check the current running status.  You can play with the output to modify this for your needs.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "SCHTASKS.exe";
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/Query /S {0} /TN {1} /FO TABLE /NH", MachineName, ScheduledTaskName);

p.Start();
// Read the error stream
string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

//Read the output string
p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
string tbl = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

//Then wait for it to finish
p.WaitForExit();

//Check for an error
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(error))
{
    throw new Exception(error);
}

//Parse output
return tbl.Split(new String[] { "\n", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1].Trim().EndsWith("Running");
```

Comment: Your return statement gives this error: Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the boun
ds of the array.

Comment: When I run it, there are 2 lines returned.  The first line looks like this:  `Folder: \`  Maybe yours is different?

Comment: Call the process manually in a command window.  `SCHTASKS.exe /Query /TN YourTaskName /FO TABLE /NH`  See what comes out.

Comment: ERROR: Invalid Argument/Option - '/TN'.
Type "SCHTASKS /QUERY /?" for usage. I did change the Taskname to mine.

Comment: I can't do everything for you.  Type `SCHTASKS /QUERY /?` and see what it says.

Comment: Apparently /TN is a argument Windows XP onwards do not accept (according to MSDN)

Comment: This does not support I18N and will only work on english-Windows OS. I prefer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12171470 this answer

Answer (score 7):

I know this is a bit late but, I really wanted to post this. (It is because I like simple code) :D

**Example of usage:**

```
MessageBox.Show("The scheduled task's existance is " + taskexistance("TASKNAMEHERE").ToString());
```

**Function:**

```
private string taskexistance(string taskname)
{
    ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
    start.FileName = "schtasks.exe"; // Specify exe name.
    start.UseShellExecute = false;
    start.CreateNoWindow = true;
    start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    start.Arguments = "/query /TN " + taskname;
    start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    // Start the process.
    using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
    {
        // Read in all the text from the process with the StreamReader.
        using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
        {
            string stdout = reader.ReadToEnd();
            if (stdout.Contains(taskname)) {
                return "true.";
            }
            else
            {
                return "false.";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Arguments = "/query /TN \"" + taskname + "\"";` in case "taskname" contains space.

Comment: @Kiquenet Try running it in the console and you can see the output. Try to isolate it from there :)

Comment: Parser the output (string) for Check state of task ?

Comment: @Kiquenet in my example above, stdout is a string that contains the output which you could parse to get the state.

Answer (score -1):

Just call schtask /Query.   The /TN option did not work only returned an ERROR.  But if you just use the /Query you can still search the output for the task.